# maintain cors headers on raise error

Tags: apigee

Hello Apigee Support team and fellow devs with questions and answers,

thanks for any support on this. this is more a confirmation than a question. when you do a raise error on apigee with FaultResponse/Set as seen here http://apigee.com/docs/ja/api-services/reference/raise-fault-policy you override the entire headers killing in the process the cors headers.

is there a way to maintain the cors headers on the raise error? or you have to manually add them?

Marco

Comment: Far as I know you have to add them manually in your default fault rule.

Answer (score 0):

create a javascript policy where you store the headers in a different variable, the set them in the RaiseError policy.

The script will look something like...

```
context.setVariable("myVariable", context.getVariable("request.header.{name}"));
```

Then in the RaiseFault use `{myVariable}` to place the value in the header.

Please provide examples of your source code if you need a more accurate answer.